# MVC 3 RAZOR - how to use hidden fields to maintain state of checkboxes between page request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, checkbox, hidden-field

I am using Hidden fields to maintain the state of my checkboxes between page requests except it doesn't work. So when I click on my webgrid to go to the next 15 records it forgets which checkboxes are checked.

**Index view**

```
@model IEnumerable<UserManager.Models.vw_UserManager_Model>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "User Manager Dashboard";
}
@Html.ActionLink("Create New User", "CreateUser")
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="webgrid-filter">
        @{Html.RenderAction("_WebGridFilter", "UserManager");}
    </div>

    <div id="webgrid-wrapper">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Partial/_WebGridUserManager.cshtml", Model)
    </div>
    <br />
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Disable checkboxs where a user is not active.
        $(".webgrid-wrapper input:not(:checked)").attr("disabled", "disabled");

        // Style tables.
        function jQueryUIStyling() {
            $('input:button, input:submit').button();

            $('.webgrid-wrapper').addClass('ui-grid ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all');
            $('.webgrid-title').addClass('ui-grid-header ui-widget-header ui-corner-top');
            jQueryTableStyling();
        } // end of jQueryUIStyling

        function jQueryTableStyling() {
            $('.webgrid').addClass('ui-grid-content ui-widget-content');
            $('.webgrid-header').addClass('ui-state-default');
            $('.webgrid-footer').addClass('ui-grid-footer ui-widget-header ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-clearfix');
        } // end of jQueryTableStyling
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function filterGrid() {
        var filters = getFilterVals();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "UserManager")',
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            dataType: "html",
            data: "alfConnect=" + filters.alfConnect + "&" + "alfIntelligence=" + filters.alfIntelligence + "&" + "brad=" + filters.brad,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#webgrid-wrapper').empty().html(data);
                //                $('#webgrid-wrapper').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function getFilterVals() {
        filters = new Object();
        if ($('.webgrid-filter #chkFilterAlfIntell').is(':checked')) {
            filters.alfIntelligence = 1;
        }
        else {
            filters.alfIntelligence = 0;
        }

        if ($('.webgrid-filter #chkFilterAlfConn').is(':checked')) {
            filters.alfConnect = 1;
        }
        else {
            filters.alfConnect = 0;
        }

        if ($('.webgrid-filter #chkFilterBrad').is(':checked')) {
            filters.brad = 1;
        }
        else {
            filters.brad = 0;
        }
        return filters;

    }

    function logUserOff(url) {
        var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to save this data?')
        if (answer) {
            //            alert(url + ": " + value);

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST"
                //                data: value
            }).done(function () {
                $(this).addClass("done");
            });


            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    };
</script>
```

**Partial view with hidden fields**

```
@model UserManager.Models.webgrid_validation
<b>@Html.Label("Select a filter: ")</b>
<br />

@Html.Label("Toggle ALF Intelligence users:")
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.chkBoxAlfIntelligence, new
{
    id = "chkFilterAlfIntell",
    onclick = "filterGrid()",
    @checked = "checked"

})
@Html.Hidden("hdnAlfIntelligence", Model.chkBoxAlfIntelligence)

@Html.Label("Toggle ALF Connect users:")
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.chkBoxAlfConnect, new
{
    id = "chkFilterAlfConn",
    onclick = "filterGrid()",
    @checked = "checked"
})
@Html.Hidden("hdnAlfConnect", Model.chkBoxAlfConnect)

@Html.Label("Toggle BRAD users:")
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.chkBoxBrad, new
{
    id = "chkFilterBrad",
    onclick = "filterGrid()",
    @checked = "checked"

})
@Html.Hidden("hdnBrad", Model.chkBoxBrad)
```

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using UserManager.Models;

namespace UserManager.Controllers
{
    public class UserManagerController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /UserManager/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            try
            {
                var model = new UserManagerTestEntities().vw_UserManager_Model;
                return View(model.ToList());

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View(ViewBag);
            }

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(int alfConnect, int alfIntelligence, int brad)
        {
            List<UserManager.Models.vw_UserManager_Model> modelList = DAL.getGrid(alfConnect, alfIntelligence, brad);


                        switch (alfConnect)
            {
                case 1:
                    ViewData["chkBoxAlfConnect"] = 1;
                    break;
                case 0:
                    ViewData["chkBoxAlfConnect"] = 0;
                    break;
            }

            switch (alfIntelligence)
            {
                case 1:
                    ViewData["chkBoxAlfIntelligence"] = 1;
                    break;
                case 0:
                    ViewData["chkBoxAlfIntelligence"] = 0;
                    break;
            }

            switch (brad)
            {
                case 1:
                    ViewData["chkBoxBrad"] = 1;
                    break;
                case 0:
                    ViewData["chkBoxBrad"] = 0;
                    break;
            }

            return PartialView("~/Views/Partial/_WebGridUserManager.cshtml", modelList);  
        }

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult _WebGridFilter ()
        {
            UserManager.Models.webgrid_validation model = new webgrid_validation();


            return PartialView("~/Views/Partial/_WebGridFilter.cshtml", model);
        }


        //public ActionResult _WebGridFilter(int alfConnect, int alfIntelligence, int brad)
        //{
        //    UserManager.Models.webgrid_validation model = new webgrid_validation();

            //switch (alfConnect)
            //{
            //    case 1:
            //        model.chkBoxAlfConnect = true;
            //        break;
            //    case 0:
            //        model.chkBoxAlfConnect = false;
            //        break;
            //}

            //switch (alfIntelligence)
            //{
            //    case 1:
            //        model.chkBoxAlfIntelligence = true;
            //        break;
            //    case 0:
            //        model.chkBoxAlfIntelligence = false;
            //        break;
            //}

            //switch (brad)
            //{
            //    case 1:
            //        model.chkBoxBrad = true;
            //        break;
            //    case 0:
            //        model.chkBoxBrad = false;
            //        break;
            //}
        //    return PartialView("~/Views/Partial/_WebGridFilter.cshtml", model);
        //}



        #region ajaxMethods
        public ActionResult LookUpGroupName(string q, int limit)
        {

            try
            {
                //TODO: Map list to autocomplete textbox control
                DAL d = new DAL();
                List<string> groups = d.groups();

                var GroupValue = groups
                    .Where(x => x.Contains(q))
                    .OrderBy(x => x)
                    .Take(limit)
                    .Select(r => new { group = r });

                // Return the result set as JSON
                return Json(GroupValue, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        public ActionResult LogUserOff(string userid)
        {

            try
            {
                //TODO: Map list to autocomplete textbox control

                return View();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        //[HttpPost]
        //public ActionResult FilterGrid(int alfConnect, int alfIntelligence, int brad)
        //{
        //    List<UserManager.Models.vw_UserManager_Model> modelList  = DAL.getGrid(alfConnect, alfIntelligence, brad);

        //    return PartialView("_WebGridUserManager", modelList);
        //}

        #endregion

        #region crud
        public ActionResult CreateUser()
        {
            //var data = new UserManager.Models.UserManagerTestEntities();
            ViewBag.Message = "Create New User";
            var model = new vw_UserManager_Model();
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateUser (vw_UserManager_Model model)
        {

                int outcome = 0;
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    //var data = new UserManager.Models.UserManagerTestEntities();
                    // Pass model to Data Layer
                     outcome = UserManager.DAL.CreateUser(model, outcome);
                    //data.SaveChanges();
                }

                if (outcome > 0) // Success
                {

                    return RedirectToAction("showSuccess", model);

                }
                else // Failure
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("showError", new { ErrorMessage = "Error" });
                }
        }

        public ActionResult EditUser(Guid userid, string salutation, string firstname, string lastname, string password, Nullable<bool> isactive,  Nullable<int> maxconcurrentusers, string email, string module, string group)
        {
            vw_UserManager_Model editUser = new vw_UserManager_Model();
            editUser.userid = userid;
            editUser.salutation = salutation;
            editUser.firstname = firstname;
            editUser.lastname = lastname;
            editUser.password = password;
            editUser.isactive = isactive;
            editUser.MaxConcurrentUsers = maxconcurrentusers;
            editUser.email = email;
            editUser.module_name = module;
            editUser.group_name = group;
            return View(editUser);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditUser(vw_UserManager_Model editUser)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                UserManager.DAL.EditUser(editUser);
            }

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult DeleteUser(Guid userid, string username, string salutation, string firstname, string lastname, string password, bool isactive, string email, string module, string group)
        {
            vw_UserManager_Model DeleteUser = new vw_UserManager_Model();
            DeleteUser.userid = userid;
            DeleteUser.UserName = username;
            DeleteUser.salutation = salutation;
            DeleteUser.firstname = firstname;
            DeleteUser.lastname = lastname;
            DeleteUser.password = password;
            DeleteUser.isactive = isactive;
            DeleteUser.email = email;
            DeleteUser.module_name = module;
            DeleteUser.group_name = group;

            return View(DeleteUser);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DeleteUser(vw_UserManager_Model deleteUser)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                UserManager.DAL.DeleteUser(deleteUser);
                return RedirectToAction("showSuccess", new { SuccessMessage = "Success" });
            }

            return View();
        }
        #endregion crud

        #region successErrorHandling
        public ActionResult showError(List<string> ErrorMessage)
        {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage[0];
                return View("ErrorMessageView");
        }

        public ActionResult showSuccess(vw_UserManager_Model model)
        {

            return View("SuccessMessageeView", model);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

My question is how to use hidden fields to maintain state of checkboxes between page request?

Answer (score 0):

you could remove the form and send data to the controller as JSon values, and thus refresh only the part of the page that needs to be refreshed.

Regards

Comment: @LiondelD Hey I ended up using session state to store values between page requests. Is this bad practise for MVC? I am using it sparingly.

Comment: Hi, in fact i do not understand where is the issue. As far as i understand your code, you have a partial view which contains checkboxes and another one with your content. The first partial view is never refreshed as the checkboxes are filters. So to me, you should handle this with a simple ajax request to an action that will return the second view updated and replace the html (this part is already done). Storing those values in session can lead to bugs if you don't manage clear correctly the values when you leave the page.

Comment: I've read you're code again. Simply remove the form should solve this. Am i wrong?